# Django settin up Media files on IIS

Tags: python, django, windows, iis

I have a Django App which creates PDF files on the server. On the development server it works well but on IIS it doesnt create the file. I have given all the persmission  yet theres no luck. I wrote a simple script to write a text file and that too doesnt work on IIS. Any help to resolve this is appriciated.

Thank you.

```
    def fileWriteTest(request):
        f = open("media/testwrite.txt", "a")
        f.write("Now the file has more content!")
        f.close()
        print("File Written!")
        return HttpResponse("Done !")
```

FileNotFoundError at /accounts/testfile/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/testwrite.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around.

'''

from django.conf import settings
import os

def fileWriteTest(request):

```
my_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str("testwrite4.txt"))

f = open(my_file, "a")
f.write("Now the file has more content!")
f.close()
print("File Written!")
return HttpResponse(str(my_file))
```

'''

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: COuld you let me know how to do this ?

Comment: To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons:https://imgur.com/a/GyEGtOr